# Merge Array of Arrays | NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, merge

I would like to know how could I merge an array of arrays. For example, I have the following array:

```
[ [ {marca: 'fiat', modelo: 'palio'} ], [ {marca: 'nissan', modelo: 'march'} ] ]
```

I'd like to get this array, after merging the array above:

```
[ {marca: 'fiat', modelo: 'palio'}, {marca: 'nissan', modelo: 'march'} ]
```

Thanks, guys, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ES6-spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in combination with Array.reduce, e.g.

```js
const arr = [ [ {marca: 'fiat', modelo: 'palio'} ], [ {marca: 'nissan', modelo: 'march'} ] ];
console.log(arr.reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try to the new, but still experimental, [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method of arrays...

```js
const input = [
  [ {marca: 'fiat', modelo: 'palio'} ],
  [ {marca: 'nissan', modelo: 'march'} ]
];

console.log(input.flat());
```

Or alternatively use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```js
const input = [
  [ {marca: 'fiat', modelo: 'palio'}, {marca: 'fiat', modelo: 'fiesta'} ],
  [ {marca: 'nissan', modelo: 'march'} ]
];

let res = input.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.push(...curr) && acc, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I would just like to point out that the 2nd example's input probably does not follow the "standard" Vinicius Martins has established, since the Fiat Fiesta item has an attribute called 'model', which is named unlike the other items' 'modelo', which is a Portuguese word that means, duh, model.   Brazilian here :)

Comment: @Gustavo6046 I'm from Argentina, and here is `modelo` also. My mistake, sorry! updated now!

Comment: It is fine! Mistakes happen. I think I paid a bit too much attention to the details when I posted that comment.  :P

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways this can be done. Assuming your input data is such that each item of the input array is an array itself with one item, the use of `Array#map` would be sufficient:

```js
const input = [
  [{
    marca: 'fiat',
    modelo: 'palio'
  }],
  [{
    marca: 'nissan',
    modelo: 'march'
  }]
];

/* 
For each subArray of input array where the subArray
is known to have a single element, extract that single
element and return it as the result of each map iteration 
*/
const output = input.map(([item]) => item)

console.log(output)
```

Alternatively, for a more general solution that "flattens" an array of array items that have variable length, you could achieve that via `Array#reduce` as follows:

```js
const input = [
  [{
    marca: 'fiat',
    modelo: 'palio'
  }, {
    test: 'foo'
  }],
  [{
    marca: 'nissan',
    modelo: 'march'
  }]
];

const output = input.reduce((finalArray, subArray) => {
  
  /* 
  For each item being iterated during reduce, concat
  the subArray to the finalArray 
  */
  return finalArray.concat(subArray);

}, [])

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, if you are using NodeJs, there is a package named array-flatten, you can install it with

```
npm install array-flatten --save
```

For example:

```
var flatten = require('array-flatten')

flatten([1, [2, [3, [4, [5], 6], 7], 8], 9])
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-flatten

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this, I would recommend [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control), as there is no need to be installing npm packages when not needed.

```js
let arrays = [
  [{
    marca: 'fiat',
    modelo: 'palio'
  }],
  [{
    marca: 'nissan',
    modelo: 'march'
  }]
]

arrays = arrays.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);

console.log(arrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used lodash's flattenDeep method to solve it. 
For example:

```
_.flattenDeep(Array)
```

Thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Where implemented, you can use the standard [Array's flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method:

```
let arr = [ [ {marca: 'fiat', modelo: 'palio'} ], [ {marca: 'nissan', modelo: 'march'} ] ];

console.log(arr.flat());
```

As alternative, if it's just a shallow flat, you can obtain the same result with `concat` and spread operator:

```
console.log([].concat(...arr));
```